# Jasmine: how to check that array contains an object?

Tags: jasmine

This check used to pass:

```
expect(array).toContain(value)
```

Array:

```
[
  {"_t":"user","id":1073970419,"email":"email3@example.org","name":"Spectator"},
  {"_t":"user","id":4464992042,"email":"email4@example.org","name":"Collaborator"},
  {"_t":"user","id":1978569710,"email":"email5@example.org","name":"Manage"}
]
```

Value:

```
{"_t":"user","id":1978569710,"email":"email5@example.org","name":"Manage"}
```

But no longer passes. Whats the new way to write the same test?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It won't contain *that* object (remember, two objects with the same properties are not the same object for the purposes of equality), so `toContain` will never pass.

You need to use another test, like `toEqual` or (if you only want to check for a subset of properties), `toEqual` combined with [`jasmine.objectContaining`](https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Partial_Matching_with_%3Ccode%3Ejasmine.objectContaining%3C/code%3E).

Here's the `toEqual` example from the Jasmine documentation on that page:

```js
describe("The 'toEqual' matcher", function() {

  it("works for simple literals and variables", function() {
    var a = 12;
    expect(a).toEqual(12);
  });

  it("should work for objects", function() {
    var foo = {
      a: 12,
      b: 34
    };
    var bar = {
      a: 12,
      b: 34
    };
    expect(foo).toEqual(bar);
  });
});
```

Note now `foo` equals `bar`.

Here's their example using `jasmine.objectContaining`:

```js
describe("jasmine.objectContaining", function() {
  var foo;

  beforeEach(function() {
    foo = {
      a: 1,
      b: 2,
      bar: "baz"
    };
  });

  it("matches objects with the expect key/value pairs", function() {
    expect(foo).toEqual(jasmine.objectContaining({
      bar: "baz"
    }));
    expect(foo).not.toEqual(jasmine.objectContaining({
      c: 37
    }));
  });

  // ...
});
```

Note how the object with several properties matches the partial object supplied to `jasmine.objectContaining`.

Comment: Thanks, how about an example for other readers? How do I rewrite the test?

Comment: @hakunin: By all means, add one if you like, I'll approve the edit when you suggest it. I just knew what the problem was, so went looking in the Jasmine docs (*wow* those are frustrating when you just want a list of matchers).

Comment: @hakunin: I've copied a couple from the docs into the answer.

Comment: I figured it out, to rewrite my spec I needed to use `arrayContaining`.

Comment: would be nice to add the solution using arrayContaining

Comment: @mazs: The above *has* the solution.

Comment: sorry, i meant the solution using `arrayContaining`

Comment: @mazs: I didn't know about `arrayContaining`, as [it's missing from this page](https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Partial_Matching_with_%3Ccode%3Ejasmine.arrayContaining%3C/code%3E). I've now found it [here](https://jasmine.github.io/api/2.8/jasmine.html). I suggest posting an answer using it, it seems like the better solution to me if it's applicable.

Comment: Can someone look at why the edit queue for this answer is full.

Answer (score 38):

The syntax you need is:

```js
const obj = {"_t":"user","id":1978569710,"email":"email5@example.org","name":"Manage"};

expect(array).toContain(jasmine.objectContaining(obj));
```

See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bblackwo/4o5u5Lmo/16/

Comment: @hakunin the accepted answer didn't explicitly show how to use `toContain()` with `jasmine.objectContaining()`, it was only implied. My answer explicitly shows how to use them together.

Comment: @YasserHussain I just added a fiddle showing a few different options that work. Could you try those?

Comment: @hakunin: Accepted answer doesn't tell about array containing object, it only tells about object containing property...

Comment: @micronyks can you iprove th eformatting of your answer? Than I'll accept it.

Answer (score 6):

@T.J.Crowder already explained precisely the problem. Just to help you a tad more, if you want to adapt your example, you'd need something like this:

```
var userA = {"_t":"user","id":1978569710,"email":"email5@example.org","name":"Manage"}

array =
[
  {"_t":"user","id":1073970419,"email":"email3@example.org","name":"Spectator"},
  {"_t":"user","id":4464992042,"email":"email4@example.org","name":"Collaborator"},
  userA
]

expect(array).toContain(userA);
```

Comment: Hey Pedro, that doesn't pass and its exactly the problem I outlined.

Comment: That's strange. It passes over here. It's slightly different because both array and variable are referring the same object. So, in this case, contains should be okay.

Comment: In that sense yes, but I don't have the same object, so its not answering my problem.